# Puppeteer-in-electron: Is it possible to open headless browser in puppeteer electron

Tags: electron, puppeteer

Is it possible to open headless browser in puppeteer electron?
I am opening the window like this:

```
const browser = await pie.connect(app, puppeteer);
const page = await pie.getPage(browser, win);
```

Comment: practically it is possible but why you need pupeeteer when you are already using electronjs. just create an electron BrowserWindow in background and use it for scrapping or whatever you want it to use for.

Comment: @anees I am using pupeteer to read some data from sites  and showing notifications. For that some times automatic login and clicking elements like actions needed that is why I am using puppeteer.(Interacting with sites without their api)

Comment: Yes, from the back-end context (the front-end one can't do it).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
const pie = require('puppeteer-in-electron')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core')

const browser = await pie.connect(app, puppeteer)
const window = new BrowserWindow({ show: false })
page = await pie.getPage(browser, window)
// ...the rest of the code
```

Seems it's the only way other than modifying puppeteer-in-electron code